# Are java.sound and java.util.RandonAccessFile fully supported on Android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, codenameone

I'm considering using codenameone to implement a cross-platform app, Win/Mac/Android/iOS. I do my development on Windows, and am fairly clueless about Mac and iOS development. Two specific features that I use quite a bit, are the java.sound API and RandomAccessFile. I was curious what the support for these on the mobile platforms was like. Would the following code samples work on mobile platforms (particularly iOS) via codenameone?

Example 1:

```
Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < mixerInfo.length; ii++) {
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[ii]);
        Info[] sli = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
        addSink(sinksModel, sli, mixer);
        Info[] tli = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
        addSource(sourcesModel, tli, mixer);
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
    /** Starts playing audio from the current file position. */
public void startPlaying() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int framePos = sendLastCue();
            playing = true;
            stopPlaying = false;
            while (!stopPlaying) {
                try {
                    int bytes = raf.read(buffer);
                    if (bytes < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    outputLine.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    framePos = sendCues(framePos);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            playing = false;
            stopPlaying = true;
            for (RecordingListener l : listeners) {
                l.playEnded();
            }

        }

    };
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

Example 3:

```
/* raf is an instance of RandomAccessFile. */
private void writeDirect(byte[] buf, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        flush();
        raf.seek(virtualFilePointer);
        raf.write(buf, offset, length);
        virtualFilePointer = raf.getFilePointer();
        virtualLength = Math.max(virtualLength, raf.length());
        virtualFilePointer = raf.getFilePointer();
        directWriteCount++;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Codename One supports a subset on those platforms and has no support for either one of those. Nor does it support NIO or similar API's that would be impractical to QA properly on native devices.

See the JavaDocs for the exact set of API's supported: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/

You can access native device functionality though thru native interfaces and do those things natively: 
http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_interfaces